# Associated primes and Noetherian condition

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $M$ an $A$-module, and $N\subset M$ a submodule. Consider the following two sets:
$$\Omega:=\{\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}A \ | \ \mathfrak{p}=(N:m) \ \mbox{for some} \ m\in M\}$$
$$\sqrt{\Omega}:=\{\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}A \ | \ \mathfrak{p}=\sqrt{(N:m)} \ \mbox{for some} \ m\in M\}$$
$(N:m)$ means $\{a\in A \ | \ am\in N\}$.
Clearly $\Omega\subset\sqrt{\Omega}$. I know from my knowledge of primary decomposition that the two sets are equal if $M$ is Noetherian. Many things in the theory of primary decomposition work if either $A$ or $M$ is Noetherian, so I have a suspicion that the two sets may be equal if $A$ is Noetherian instead of $M$, but I can't seem to prove it. Is it true at all? I can show that if $A$ is Noetherian, then $\bigcup\Omega=\bigcup\sqrt{\Omega}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{p}=\sqrt{(N:m)}$, then $\mathfrak p$ is minimal over $(N:m)$, that is, $\mathfrak p$ is *weakly* associated. But for noetherian rings weakly associated primes are associated. (More details [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546).)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I find it fascinating!

Comment: @ashpool No surprise! Bourbaki introduced this terminology under the name *faiblement associé*.